# Matching in bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Hi guys, I'm new here.
Well, actually I'm studying graph theory and the follow question is driving me crazy. Any hint in any direction would be appreciated.

Here is the question:

Let $G = G[X, Y]$ a bipartite graph in which each vertex in X is of odd degree. Suppose at any two vertices of X have an even number of common neighbours.
Show that G has matching covering every vertex of X.

Comment: Probably not appropriate for this site. But, what theorems do you know about existence of perfecting matchings which could be applied?

Comment: Hi.
What isn't appropriate? I didn't understand...

About the matchings, well, first of all X and Y couldn't have the same size what would imply to be impossible to find a perfect matching. ( I know it is an obvious comment but I made it to be sure that the problem it is clear)

I thought it would be just a clever application of Hall's theorem... So, answering your question, I have hall's theorem.

Comment: What's inappropriate is that this looks like homework, and you have given us no reason that it is not. Voting to close.

Comment: Also posted, without advising either site, to m.se: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213923/matching-in-bipartite-graphs#comment482872_213923 --- voting to close. 

Comment: R.R: The reason it looks like homework is not the question itself (mathematically, it's quite nice), but the lack of context.

Comment: Hi, everyone.
I don't know what kind of problem could be classified as homework. But, honestly I think it is hard to judge. 

Graph theory it is a wide subject and broadly applied in many other fields, even in mathematics. Actually, I'm a PhD student working in percolation. The approach it is to study percolation using finite random graphs results and when you are using this kind of technique, sometimes you must to know the graph geometry and any graph knowledge is useful and desirable.
I left here a little reference about what I'm saying

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207112v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a homework problem? (If so, it is a nice one and new to me.) So you need to rule out the existence of a set $A \subseteq X$ such that the set $B$ of all $y \in Y$ adjacent to some $a \in A$ has strictly smaller size. Let $|B|=m$ and think of the neighbors of each $a \in A$ as a vector in $\mathbb{Z}_2^m.$ Each pair of these vecotrs is orthogonal in that their dot product is zero in $\mathbb{Z}_2.$ See what that tells you.

Comment: It's a nice argument, but answering homework problems is completely inappropriate.

Comment: The argument works. The hypothesis gives a linearly independent subset of a vector space which dimension is m.

Thanks